# Add dns record just for subdomain (Windows server 2008 ).

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

We host one web app on our server and the domain for this app is registerd at our isp and also the DNS records are there. 
From our company computers the app is accessible via internal IP (let's say IP A), and the outside adrress for this server is sometihg else (let's call it IP B).

What I want is that the domain for the app is resolved into ip A, when we are browsing on our company computers.

So when I sit at my company computer I want get the following:

- thing.com -> ip B (our domain must still resolve into ip B)
- some.thing.com -> ip A (only this subdomain must resolve into ip
  A)10.64.16.60
- no.thing.com -> ip B (any other subdomain for thing.com must resolve
  into ip B)

We are runing windows 2008 server with AD and DNS installed.
If I add new zone "thing.com" under Forward Lookup Zones and then add A record for "some" which points to ip A, then it works as desired for "some.thing.com", but for anything else it doesn't.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Can you add a record to your ISP DNS servers? You should be able to add some.thing.com on there with your internal IP address with no risk. Anyone who looks up "some.thing.com" from the Internet will still get an internal result but this is only a cosmetic error really, as they won't be on your private network to be able to connect to that IP address...slightly ugly but should work.

Comment: No this won't work. We still need for users outside our copmany to get  "some.thing.com" corectlly resolved into ip B.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I assumed this was for some kind of internal development environment. I'm not sure whether this is achievable on Windows, it would expect to act as authoritative for a whole domain rather than just one record within it. Is your external server a dedicated/VPS server? What OS is on it? BIND on a Unix OS can do this by using "views", but I don't think Windows Server offers this feature in its DNS Server role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an authoritative zone for `some.thing.com`, and create an `A` record for `@` (windows DNS calls this "(same as parent folder)") pointing to the internal address.

Requests for other records under thing.com will be forwarded or recursively looked up, as the server will only be authoritative for the `some.thing.com` zone.

Comment: It works and it's plain and simple solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your subdomain zone (some.thing.com) on your internal DNS server, and set up that server as recursive, using your ISP as the forwarder.  Then point your internal workstations to your internal DNS.  Queries for any other subdomains of thing.com or thing.com itself will be forwarded to your ISP's DNS.